# Is it possible to link a new text style to the list styles?

Tags: macos, pages, template

I'm making a custom template in Pages 5.5.3 app on OS X 10.10.

I've created a new text-style for my bulletpoints, but pages does always select the 'main text' for the bullet points.. Is it possible to link my new style to the list styles?

[image]